# Generating function of a random walk

Tags: random-walk, moment-generating-function, probability-generating-fn

Consider a random walk with $S_n=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$, where the random i.i.d. steps $X_i$ take values $-1,0,2$ with probabilities $1/9,1/9,7/9$ respectively. Set $S_0=1$.

I would like to calculate the generating function of $S_n,G(T)=E(T^{S_n})$.

Here's my attempt:

$$G_{S_n}(t)=E(t^{S_n})=E\left(\prod^n_{i=1}t^{X_i}\right)=G_X(t)^n$$

Where independence of $X_i$ was used, and

$$G_X(t)=E(t^X)=1+\frac{1}{9}t^{-1}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{7}{9}t^2$$

Would this be correct?

Comment: When $t=1,$ obviously $E[t^{S_n}]=1.$ When you plug $t=1$ into your expression for $G_X,$ what value do you obtain?