# Termination of the random walk

Tags: expected-value, random-walk

Consider a random walk with $S_n=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$, where the random i.i.d. steps $X_i$ take values $-1,0,2$ with probabilities $1/9,1/9,7/9$ respectively. Set $S_0=1$.

The walk terminated whenever it either steps on the right boundary at $40$ or oversteps it by $1$ (i.e, terminates at $41$). The left boundary at $0$ is reflecting: whenever it is reached, the next step is either $1$ or $3$, with probabilities $\frac{2}{9}$ and $\frac{7}{9}$, respectively.

I would like to determine the expected time until the walk terminates.

I have calculated the expected value of the random walk in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/540002/expected-value-of-random-walk), however I have no idea how to answer when it will terminate. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The reflection would make more sense at $1$ than at $0$ if the next positions are $1$ or $3$

Comment: I do not see a simple way of doing this, but if you adjust the reflection as I suggested then the expected number of steps from $1$ to $40$ or $41$ seems to be  about $27.229$, which is not far from $\frac9{13}\left(\frac{40+41}2-1\right)$